# Quarkus remote dev mode mutable jar startup failed

Tags: quarkus, kogito

I am trying to run quarkus in remote dev mode and when I try to deploy (AKS) getting the error
**Paths collection expected to contain a single path but contains 0**

I am using both camel and kogito capabilities in my project. The code works fine in my local machine. Only during deployment facing the issue.

I have configured the below in the **application.properties** files

```
quarkus.package.type=mutable-jar
quarkus.live-reload.password=changeit
quarkus.live-reload.url=http://localhost:8080
```

and also mentioned the **pom.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>rules-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.13.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.31</freemarker.version>
        <volante-version>6.2.0</volante-version>


        <camel-quarkus.platform.group-id>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</camel-quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <camel-quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-camel-bom</camel-quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <camel-quarkus.platform.version>${quarkus.platform.version}</camel-quarkus.platform.version>

        <kogito.bom.group-id>org.kie.kogito</kogito.bom.group-id>
        <kogito.bom.artifact-id>kogito-bom</kogito.bom.artifact-id>
        <kogito.bom.version>1.29.0.Final</kogito.bom.version>


        <camel.version>3.16.0</camel.version>
    </properties>




    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-camel-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>

            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-kogito-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>

            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${camel-quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${camel-quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${camel-quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${kogito.bom.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${kogito.bom.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${kogito.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-log</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-yaml-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-xml-io-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-seda</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
        <!--  <dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jsonpath-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
-->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.quarkus/camel-quarkus-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.quarkus/camel-quarkus-xml-jaxb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-xml-jaxb</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-atlasmap</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>






        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-kafka</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-reactive-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-direct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-direct</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-timer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-timer</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.kogito</groupId>
            <artifactId>kogito-quarkus-rules</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
 
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie.kogito</groupId>
    <artifactId>kogito-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
            
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-mutiny</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        





        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.kogito</groupId>
            <artifactId>kogito-drools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                                        </native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
                                        </java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

**Full Error :**

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/quarkus-app/lib/main/org.jboss.slf4j.slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.2.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/quarkus-app/lib/main/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.2.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory]
Press [h] for more options>
2022-10-21 14:42:37,677 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.dep.mai.CamelMainHotDeploymentProcessor] (build-44) HotDeployment files:
2022-10-21 14:42:37,677 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.dep.mai.CamelMainHotDeploymentProcessor] (build-44) - routes/http.yaml
2022-10-21 14:42:37,677 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.dep.mai.CamelMainHotDeploymentProcessor] (build-44) - routes/orchestrator.xml
2022-10-21 14:42:37,677 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.dep.mai.CamelMainHotDeploymentProcessor] (build-44) - routes/updatedrlcontent.xml
2022-10-21 14:42:37,677 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.dep.mai.CamelMainHotDeploymentProcessor] (build-44) - routes/notification.xml
2022-10-21 14:42:37,677 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.dep.mai.CamelMainHotDeploymentProcessor] (build-44) - routes/commonlogger.xml
2022-10-21 14:42:47,276 WARN  [io.qua.arc.dep.SplitPackageProcessor] (build-53) Detected a split package usage which is considered a bad practice and should be avoided. Following packages were detected in multiple archives:
- "org.apache.camel.spring" found in [org.apache.camel:camel-spring-main::jar, org.apache.camel:camel-spring::jar]
2022-10-21 14:42:48,683 INFO  [org.kie.kog.cod.api.uti.AddonsConfigDiscovery] (build-59) Performed addonsConfig discovery, found: AddonsConfig{usePersistence=false, useTracing=false, useMonitoring=false, usePrometheusMonitoring=false, useCloudEvents=false, useExplainability=false, useProcessSVG=false, useEventDrivenDecisions=false, useEventDrivenRules=false}
2022-10-21 14:42:51,468 WARN  [org.tes.uti.TestcontainersConfiguration] (build-34) Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/project/%3F/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: /project/?/.testcontainers.properties (No such file or directory)
2022-10-21 14:42:51,974 INFO  [org.kie.kog.cod.cor.uti.ApplicationGeneratorDiscovery] (build-73) Generator discovery performed, found [rules]
2022-10-21 14:42:51,982 INFO  [org.kie.kog.cod.cor.ApplicationGenerator] (build-73) Skipping generator 'rules' because disabled
2022-10-21 14:42:52,069 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy] (build-34) docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([/usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin, /opt/graalvm/bin])
2022-10-21 14:42:52,070 ERROR [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-34) Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
2022-10-21 14:42:52,071 ERROR [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-34)     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
2022-10-21 14:42:52,071 ERROR [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-34) As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
2022-10-21 14:42:52,087 WARN  [io.qua.dep.IsDockerWorking] (build-34) No docker binary found or general error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Input/Output error while executing command.
2022-10-21 14:42:52,088 WARN  [io.qua.kaf.cli.dep.DevServicesKafkaProcessor] (build-34) Docker isn't working, please configure the Kafka bootstrap servers property (kafka.bootstrap.servers).
2022-10-21 14:42:52,168 WARN  [io.qua.mon.dep.DevServicesMongoProcessor] (build-42) Please configure datasource URL for default datasource or get a working docker instance
2022-10-21 14:42:55,278 INFO  [org.kie.kog.qua.com.dep.KogitoAssetsProcessor] (build-46) reflectiveEfestoGeneratedClassBuildItem org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoGeneratedSourcesBuildItem@582bd63a
2022-10-21 14:42:55,473 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2022-10-21 14:42:57,386 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.4.3.Final
2022-10-21 14:42:58,879 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor#generateModel threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Paths collection expected to contain a single path but contains 0
        at io.quarkus.paths.PathList.getSinglePath(PathList.java:81)
        at org.drools.drl.quarkus.util.deployment.DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.createJavaCompilerSettings(DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.java:155)
        at org.drools.drl.quarkus.util.deployment.DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.compileGeneratedSources(DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.java:139)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor.createGeneratedBeanBuildItemsFromJavaSources(KogitoAssetsProcessor.java:272)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor.generateModel(KogitoAssetsProcessor.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:335)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:86)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:447)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:59)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:149)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.mutability.DevModeTask.main(DevModeTask.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.DevModeMediator.doStart(DevModeMediator.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.DevModeMediator.doDevMode(DevModeMediator.java:34)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:46)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor#generateModel threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Paths collection expected to contain a single path but contains 0
        at io.quarkus.paths.PathList.getSinglePath(PathList.java:81)
        at org.drools.drl.quarkus.util.deployment.DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.createJavaCompilerSettings(DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.java:155)
        at org.drools.drl.quarkus.util.deployment.DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.compileGeneratedSources(DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.java:139)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor.createGeneratedBeanBuildItemsFromJavaSources(KogitoAssetsProcessor.java:272)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor.generateModel(KogitoAssetsProcessor.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Paths collection expected to contain a single path but contains 0
        at io.quarkus.paths.PathList.getSinglePath(PathList.java:81)
        at org.drools.drl.quarkus.util.deployment.DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.createJavaCompilerSettings(DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.java:155)
        at org.drools.drl.quarkus.util.deployment.DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.compileGeneratedSources(DroolsQuarkusResourceUtils.java:139)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor.createGeneratedBeanBuildItemsFromJavaSources(KogitoAssetsProcessor.java:272)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.common.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor.generateModel(KogitoAssetsProcessor.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

Comment: Hi! Do you have a reproducer where I can see the whole project or part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue will be handled in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-8183
We need a reproducer for full investigation, else it will be hard to target the real issue from our side.